# Loading a new version of a jar, old serialization will not work

Tags: java, serialization

Okay, so I have a jar, jar A, and another jar, jar B. Jar B is old, and I have just used it to serialize an object to a file. I shut down the running jar B, and download jar A to replace jar B. The problem with this is that A has a few new/missing fields compared to B. **Is there any way that I could use a copy of jar B to load the serialized object, then move that over to A?** (Or any other solution you can think of)

And just so everyone knows, I cannot use external libraries.
Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you have access to the source for the JARs. I'm assuming you do not, given the question. If that is the case, you could use a custom class loader that uses JAR B, loads the given class, and then you'd have to convert that to a non Object format (XML, JSON, String, etc) so that you could call your other class that could create a new A Object with the information in the string.

If this is just a one time conversion, it might be easier to just have an application that uses JAR B, loads the class and saves it into a non-Serialized form (Again, XML, JSON, text, etc) and that could then be loaded by your real application using JAR A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide serial version Id in class definition of the object you are serializing, and then you need to keep it same in both the jars A and B. Once this is done you should be able to deserialize a file with jar B which was serialized using jar A.

You can read the article http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/ for an example.